# How can I make this array mapping in a more elegant way in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to get categories arrays from all objects of the main array and merge them in one array.

```
const allItems = res.map((item) => item.categories)[0]
```

How can it be done correctly?

Comment: this simply pulls `res[0].categories`, right?

Comment: as georg said, though you could destructure `const [{categories}] = res;`

Comment: As you have working code, this question would be more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). However, it is strange that you use a mapper when you're only interested in the value of the first array element.

Comment: You should first describe your array and how a single object is made.

Comment: @georg I need to extract nested categories array from all objects located in the main array and merge them all together inside allItems

Comment: @DonDiego I need to extract nested categories array from all objects located in the main array and merge them all together inside allItems

Comment: That is a very different question than the one you asked. You need to provide more details including input and expected output if you want accurate help.

Comment: moreover, your logic is wrong: you are putting in allItems only the first ARRAY called "categories", not the single elements in it; nor all the elements of all items

Answer (score 0):

Well Why you map all the items and get only the first one?

You can:

```js
const res = [
   {categories: "a"},
   {categories: "b"},
   {categories: "c"},
];

const categories =  res[0].categories;

console.log(categories);
```

Comment: @pilchard tnx! fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to put all elements of `categories` array into the same array (which at start is an array of objects).

So, since you didn't put any code, I suppose `allItems` is the following:

```
var allItems = [
    { 
        one: "a",
        categories: ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"]
    },
    { 
        two: "b",
        categories: ["cat4", "cat5", "cat6"]
    },
    {
        three: "c",
        categories: ["cat7", "cat8", "cat9"]
    }
]
```

using

```
allItems = allItems.map(item =>item.categories).flat()
```

makes `allItems` filled of all the elements of `item.categories`

```
["cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat5", "cat6", "cat7", "cat8", "cat9"]
```